# Describe all solutions of $Ax=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The question is:

> Let $A=$ \begin{bmatrix}
>     1 & 1 & 1 & 5 \\
>     2 & 2 & 2 & 10 \\
>   \end{bmatrix}
>   Describe all solutions of $Ax=0$.

Immediately I can recognize that one of the rows can be turned into a row of zeroes: \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 & 5 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  \end{bmatrix}

But I get stuck here. I get that $x=-x_2-x_3-5x_4$, but how do I go from there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose $x_2,x_3$ and $x_4$ freely, and they will determine $x_1$.

The solutions look like $\begin{pmatrix} -s-t-5u\\s\\t\\u\end{pmatrix}$.  Or $\{s\begin{pmatrix}-1\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}+t\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}+u\begin{pmatrix}-5\\0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}\mid s,t,u\in \mathbb R\}$.

Since there are $3$ free variables,  this kernel is $3$ dimensional.